# The function "getRenderProxy" to get a ThreeJS Mesh from an object's fragId in Forge Viewer doesn't work correctly

Tags: three.js, autodesk-forge

I'm trying to get a threeJS Mesh from Autodek Forge objects using the function
'viewer.impl.getRenderProxy(viewer.model, fragId)'.
The problem that I encounter is if I put this function in a loop routine to get Meshs of multiple objects, I get just a random Mesh.

To find out the problem's origin, I used a similar function that is :
'viewer.impl.getFragmentProxy(viewer.model, fragId)'
and it worked just fine.

Her is the routine code that I use and the result :

```
                            for(let i = 0, len = nodNamee.length; i < (len); i = i+3){
                                var instanceTree = viewer.model.getData().instanceTree;

                                var fragIds = [];

                                instanceTree.enumNodeFragments(nodNamee[i+1], function(fragId){
                                    fragIds.push(fragId);
                                    
                                });

                                fragIds.forEach(function(fragId) {
                                    
                                    var renderProxy = viewer.impl.getRenderProxy(viewer.model, fragId);
                                    fragtoMesh.push(renderProxy);
                                    //var fragmentproxy = viewer.impl.getFragmentProxy(viewer.model, fragId);
                                    //fragtoProxy.push(fragmentproxy);
                                });
                            }
```

Result :
[Arry of fragtoMesh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j1Z29.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the `getFragmentProxy` method always returns the *same instance* of `THREE.Mesh`, just with different properties. Basically, the method works like this under the hood:

```js
let cachedMesh = new THREE.Mesh();

// ...
getRenderProxy(model, fragId) {
    // Find the geometry, material, and other properties of the fragment
    cachedMesh.geometry = fragGeometry;
    cachedMesh.material = fragMaterial;
    // ...
    return cachedMesh;
}
// ...
```

Note that this is a performance optimization because if the `getFragmentProxy` (which is only meant for internal use) function returned a new instance every time it's called by other parts of Forge Viewer, it would cause a huge memory churn.

So in your case, if you really need to store all the `THREE.Mesh` instances in an array, you'll need to clone them or copy their individual properties into separate `THREE.Mesh` objects.