# How to fix 'n.computeBoundingBox is not a function' error while using THREE.Mesh?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

1. ---

```
fragIds.forEach(function(fragId){ 

            var fragProxy = Viewer.impl.getFragmentProxy(
                Viewer.model,
            fragId)

            fragProxy.getAnimTransform()
            
            //fragProxy.parameters

            console.log('frag position in LCS before transform:' + 
                            fragProxy.position.x + ','+
                            fragProxy.position.y + ','+ 
                            fragProxy.position.z);

            var wcsMatrix = new THREE.Matrix4(); 
            fragProxy.getWorldMatrix(wcsMatrix);
            var wcsPos = wcsMatrix.getPosition();
            console.log('frag position in wcs matrix  before transform: ' + 
            wcsPos.x + ' ' + wcsPos.y + ' ' + wcsPos.z);
            

            
            //fragProxy.position.set(wcsPos.x/2, wcsPos.y/2, wcsPos.z/2);
            const material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ color: 0xff0000 });
            const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(fragProxy, material);
            //mesh.position.y=wcsPos.y/2;
            mesh.scale.y=2;
            console.log( mesh.matrixWorld);
            mesh.matrixWorld.setPosition(100,0,0);
           
            Viewer.impl.scene.add(mesh);
            fragProxy.updateAnimTransform()  ;
            mesh.updateMatrixWorld();
        }); 
        Viewer.impl.sceneUpdated(true)
```

```
297Viewer3DImpl.js:3566 Uncaught TypeError: n.computeBoundingBox is not a function
    at Viewer3DImpl.js:3566:30
    at K.Mesh.traverse (three.js:7986:3)
    at K.Scene.traverse (three.js:7990:23)
    at xt (Viewer3DImpl.js:3537:16)
    at _e.getVisibleBounds (Viewer3DImpl.js:3603:13)
    at Ze (Viewer3DImpl.js:619:31)
    at _e.tick (Viewer3DImpl.js:695:13)
    at e (Viewer3DImpl.js:1993:27)
```

---

while using const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(fragProxy, material); I am getting this type of error  which I tried to solve in many ways

Can someone share their thoughts to help me with this situation ?

Answer (score 0):

The fragProxy is an instance of `THREE.Mesh` already, so you cannot do `const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(fragProxy, material);`. See here for details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69105044

If you want to create a new mesh upon a viewer's native object, please use `getRenderProxy` instead. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/69105044

Here is an example I used for [RoomLocatorExtension](https://github.com/autodesk-platform-services/aps-extensions/blob/main/public/extensions/RoomLocatorExtension/contents/main.js):

```js
getComponentGeometryInfo(dbId, model) {
    const viewer = this.viewer;
    const viewerImpl = viewer.impl;
    const fragIds = this.getLeafFragIds(model, dbId);
    let matrixWorld = null;

    const meshes = fragIds.map((fragId) => {
        const renderProxy = viewerImpl.getRenderProxy(model, fragId);

        const geometry = renderProxy.geometry;
        const attributes = geometry.attributes;
        const positions = geometry.vb ? geometry.vb : attributes.position.array;

        const indices = attributes.index.array || geometry.ib;
        const stride = geometry.vb ? geometry.vbstride : 3;
        const offsets = geometry.offsets;

        matrixWorld = matrixWorld || renderProxy.matrixWorld.elements;

        return {
            positions,
            indices,
            offsets,
            stride
        };
    });

    return {
        matrixWorld,
        meshes
    };
}

getComponentGeometry(data, vertexArray) {
    const offsets = [
        {
            count: data.indices.length,
            index: 0,
            start: 0
        }
    ];

    for (let oi = 0, ol = offsets.length; oi < ol; ++oi) {
        let start = offsets[oi].start;
        let count = offsets[oi].count;
        let index = offsets[oi].index;

        for (let i = start, il = start + count; i < il; i += 3) {
            const a = index + data.indices[i];
            const b = index + data.indices[i + 1];
            const c = index + data.indices[i + 2];

            const vA = new THREE.Vector3();
            const vB = new THREE.Vector3();
            const vC = new THREE.Vector3();

            vA.fromArray(data.positions, a * data.stride);
            vB.fromArray(data.positions, b * data.stride);
            vC.fromArray(data.positions, c * data.stride);

            vertexArray.push(vA);
            vertexArray.push(vB);
            vertexArray.push(vC);
        }
    }
}

buildComponentMesh(data) {
    const vertexArray = [];

    for (let idx = 0; idx < data.nbMeshes; ++idx) {
        const meshData = {
            positions: data['positions' + idx],
            indices: data['indices' + idx],
            stride: data['stride' + idx]
        }

        this.getComponentGeometry(meshData, vertexArray);
    }

    const geometry = new THREE.Geometry();

    for (let i = 0; i < vertexArray.length; i += 3) {
        geometry.vertices.push(vertexArray[i]);
        geometry.vertices.push(vertexArray[i + 1]);
        geometry.vertices.push(vertexArray[i + 2]);

        const face = new THREE.Face3(i, i + 1, i + 2);
        geometry.faces.push(face);
    }

    const matrixWorld = new THREE.Matrix4();
    matrixWorld.fromArray(data.matrixWorld);

    const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry);
    mesh.applyMatrix(matrixWorld);
    mesh.boundingBox = data.boundingBox;
    mesh.bsp = new ThreeBSP(mesh)
    mesh.dbId = data.dbId;

    return mesh;
}
```